# copy button is working always only for the latest link

Tags: javascript

I need some advice.
After loading a new line, the copy button for other lines does not work for me. It always copies only the first link, even if I click on another button.
Thank for any advice.
Hi, I need some advice.
After loading a new line, the copy button for other lines does not work for me. It always copies only the first link, even if I click on another button.
Thank for any advice.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const inputField = container.querySelector("input");
var button = container.querySelector("button");
const showData = document.querySelector(".showData");

button.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    const linkInput = inputField.value;
    // console.log(linkInput);

    fetch(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${linkInput}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>{
            // console.log(data)

            inputField.value = "";

            var apiData = `
                <div class="data">
                    <h5>${data.result.short_link}</h5>
                    <button onclick="copyButton()" class="button__copy">Copy</button>
                </div>
            `;
            showData.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', apiData);
        })
});

// Copy to clipboard
const element = document.querySelector(".link__item__button");

function copyButton() {
    const cb = navigator.clipboard;
    const shortLink = document.querySelector('.link__item__short');
    cb.writeText(shortLink.innerText);
}
```

```css
*{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container{
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        input{
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
            border: 3px solid blue;
        }
        button{
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .showData {
            margin: 30px 0 0 0;
            line-height: 3;
        }
        .data{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .data .button__copy{
            width: 100px;
            height: 40px;
            background: lightblue;
            margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
        }
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Short URL Generator</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="paste your long link here">
            <button>Create a Link</button>

            <div class="showData">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy function does **not** work here in code snippet or on online sites with an `iframe` because of safety policy.
If you create a page without one, works fine. I checked.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const inputField = container.querySelector("input");
const button = container.querySelector("button");
const showData = document.querySelector(".showData");

button.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    const linkInput = inputField.value;

    fetch(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${linkInput}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>{

            inputField.value = "";
            const shortLink = data.result.short_link
            const id = shortLink.substring(shortLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)

            const apiData = `
                <div class="data">
                    <h5 id="${id}">${shortLink}</h5>
                    <button onclick="copyButton('${id}')" class="button__copy">Copy</button>
                </div>
            `;
            showData.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', apiData);
        })
});

function copyButton(id) {
    const shortLink = document.querySelector('#' + id);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(shortLink.innerText).then(() => {
      console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
    }, (err) => {
      console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
    });
}
```

```css
*{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
input{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
button{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.showData {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    line-height: 3;
}
.data{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.data .button__copy{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Short URL Generator</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="paste your long link here">
            <button>Create a Link</button>
            <div class="showData"></div>
        </div>
```